# why is this showing in the app ?Is it a problem with dropdownbutton?

Tags: flutter

The problem was shown only after I added value to show the options in dropdown button.[The image showed red screen instead of the app which said something about value should'nt be null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlBiK.jpg)

code was

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
_MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var _calculation = ["Sum ", "Subtraction", "Division", "Multiplication"];
  var _currentItemselected = "Add";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
          DropdownButton<String>(
            items: _calculation.map((String dropdownStringItem) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: dropdownStringItem,
                child: Text(dropdownStringItem),
);
            }).toList(),
            onChanged: (String newValueSelected) {
              setState(() {
                this._currentItemselected = newValueSelected;
});
value:_currentItemselected;
},
},
```

Comment: The code you posted and the code in the error message doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

The initial value of Of DropDownButton should be one of the items of list.

For example, add the value of `_currentSelectedIndex` to the list.

```
_calculation = ["Add", "Sum ", "Subtraction", "Division", "Multiplication"];
```